# Transfer of low density solids

Tags: manufacturing-engineering, flow-control

Which sort of equipment is specifically designed for flowing/pumping low density solids (powders) e.g. for loading from a drum to a receiver?

Comment: Equipment designed to avoid building a static charge.

Comment: for less powdery and more pellet-like granular solids, there are vacuum/pneumatic transport systems, that essentially just pipe it around. Have seen these used extensively to transport resin pellets to dozens of molding machines from a central area of building, or even between buildings.  For a single drum, just a big funnel. Similar to hopper in answer below, but smaller. Maybe something to hold the drum while it's tilted on its side (with cap removed) or even partially inverted. Not for fluffy powders however.

Comment: Auger screws, spring augers, vacuum conveyors, chain conveyors (if you can tip the drum into a hopper), ...

Comment: @PeteW this is slightly powdery. Some sort of vacuum would be my preference but a standard vacuum pipe to a hopper (with valves in-between) is very slow . I thought maybe some sort of cyclonic system?

Comment: Maybe, don't know. Haven't been involved with the powders at all, to be honest, it's all mixed into liquid by the time I get within sight of it.

Answer (score 3):

Conical hopper with gate control.

[image]

Comment: How does the solid get from the ground to the hopper? What bulk density does this cater for?

Answer (score 0):

The methods are as varied as your imagination.  Here's a few:

- Screw conveyor
- live bottom feed bin
- conical bin with or without agitation
- Air-veyance
- Shovels
- Bags (like flour) you pick up and dump
- Supersacks with tied off bottom chutes
- drum dumpers

I would expect that very common would be gravity  methods combined with conveyors to get the material up so you can use gravity.